# Regular Expression to match code blocks, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string, string-matching

I have code blocks that can looks like this:

```
"func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {\n    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y\n    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height\n    \n    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.height {\n\n        //print\n\n        if vievModel.!paginationFinished {\n            self.viewModel.loadMoreData()\n            self.tableView.reloadData()\n        }\n    }\n}\n"
```

How do I create a regex that match a bunch of code-related keywords like: **func, let, if, self** etc...

My current code for regex match is:

```
func matches(in text: String) -> [String] {
    guard let regex = regex else { return [] }
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

And I tried different regex like:

```
|\b(?<keyword>func|let|self)\b
```

and

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9])(|func|let|self)([^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

But I'm still getting an empty array in my `matches` function.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What was wrong with `\b(?<keyword>func|let|self)\b`?

Comment: I don't know it it has something to do with spaces or "\n" but the output of my matches function is []

Comment: I apply those regex to markdown text, if it might help

Comment: See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lr9BsQ/1), what do you need to match here?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. With your Regex Demo I find 5 matches, but my code still returns []. Do you have any idea if I am missing something?

Comment: You must be using `"\b"` when you need `"\\b"` or `#"\b"#`. You do not show how you instantiate the `regex` variable. You must add it to the question.

Comment: I added the regex inside a txt file, but after adding inline in my code with # # it solved my issue.